# for loop with fopen in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a function that compares two text file

```
function [testStatus, testMessage] = compareTxtFiles(File1, File2)
```

I want to create a function that opens and read two text file(File1 and File2) and returns the data to an output Data. The Data of each file is the returned to lines1 and lines2 respectively

This is my idea of the implementation. Please, I would be grateful to get some feedback

```
function Data = readFile(File)
    Data = {};

    FID = fopen(File, 'r'); 

    Data = textscan(FID, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n', 'whitespace', '');   

    fclose(FID); 
end

Data = readFile(File1);

lines1 = Data{1};  

Data = readFile(File2);

lines2 = Data{1};
```

Comment: Why do you need a for loop, you've already opened both of the files. Do you want to compare them now or just open them?

Comment: I want to open and compare them. My lecturer recommended that I should create a sub function for that, so I am thinking of using a for loop

Comment: `compareTxtFiles` does not need a loop. You need a loop that *calls* `compareTxtFile` for each pair of files.

Comment: This is his comment: Duplicated code in Lines 20-27 and 29-36
Make [sub-]function out of it.

Comment: That's very different from a for loop. What I think he means is that you call `fopen`, `textscan`, and `fclose` for *each* of the files. You could encapsulate this in another function which simply returns `Data{1}` then you'd call it twice (once for `File1` and once for `File2`)

Comment: @Maliva Please read `Code Blocks` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Now, what do you think is wrong with your code? It looks okay to me.

Comment: The code works well now. I want to to make it compatible to run in Linux? Can I use filesep?